# Pell's equation has high solutions when d is a member of OEIS A008784

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let

- $x(d),\, y(d),\, d$ and $n$ be natural numbers, such that
- $(x(d))^2-d(y(d))^2=1$.

I denote the $x$ solution $x(\textrm{dmax})$, if $x(\textrm{dmax}) > x(d)$ in the interval $n^2<d<(n+1)^2$ (I have some difficulties in the description and I  don't know the natural name for this type of  series, but in a temporal series it would be called a series of all time high – between two squares). This means that $x(\textrm{dmax})$ constitutes an increasing series between squares.

We get the results for $\textrm{dmax} = 2, 5, 10, 13, \ldots$. Note that $d=n^2+1$ is included in the $\textrm{dmax}$ series by definition, being the first case of for $d>n^2$. For $d=2$ to $d=113$, I get the 30 numbers of $\textrm{dmax}$. I compare this sequence $2, 5, 10, 13, \ldots$ with [OEIS A008784](http://oeis.org/A008784) – *“Numbers n such that sqrt(-1) mod n exists; or, numbers n that are primitively represented by $x^2+y^2$”*.
A008784 has 27 numbers $\le 113$ of which only 25 are relevant here since the sequence contains $1$ and $25$, both squares. These two series have 21 numbers in common. The less obvious cases (other than the 9 cases where $d=n^2+1$ which is by definition both a member of A008784 and $\textrm{dmax}$ are still impressive.
I therefore speculate that the requirement
$d=a^2+b^2$ or $x^2 = (ay)^2+(by)^2+1$ may (often) rule out small solutions.

I note after a  puzzle with $x^2, (ay)^2$ and $(by)^2\ (\mathrm{mod} 8)$ that $x^2=1 (\mathrm{mod} 8)$ but I find that $x$ is only $1$ or $3$ and not $5$ or $7\ (\mathrm{mod} 8)$ in my cases ($d=2-106$). Do you think this is enough to explain the large number of common terms of the two sequences?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: found Mordell's proof I mention below, [number theory - approximate square root of a prime number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318696/number-theory-approximate-square-root-of-a-prime-number/318725#318725)

ORIGINAL: I will do more fiddling with this later, but I think there is a simple answer: for the numbers $d$ for which there exists a square root of $-1,$ there is often a solution to negative Pell $$  u^2 - d v^2 = -1.  $$ Then the first solution to positive Pell is $$  (u^2 + d v^2)^2 - d (2uv)^2 = 1.  $$ For your $d=n^2 +1,$ you get $u=n,v=1$ and so $(2n^2 + 1)^2 - (n^2 + 1)(2n)^2 = 1.$ So, there is a mechanism that will tend to enlarge the entries in the positive Pell solution.

Other example

==========

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ cd "old drive"
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive$ cd home
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home$ cd jagy
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy$ cd Cplusplus
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
85

0  form   1 18 -4   delta  -4
1  form   -4 14 9   delta  1
2  form   9 4 -9   delta  -1
3  form   -9 14 4   delta  4
4  form   4 18 -1   delta  -18
5  form   -1 18 4   delta  4
6  form   4 14 -9   delta  -1
7  form   -9 4 9   delta  1
8  form   9 14 -4   delta  -4
9  form   -4 18 1   delta  18
10  form   1 18 -4

 disc   340
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-6805  -123984
-30996  -564733


 Pell automorph 
-285769  -2634660
-30996  -285769

Pell unit 
-285769^2 - 85 * -30996^2 = 1 

=========================================

Pell NEGATIVE 
378^2 - 85 * 41^2 = -1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

==============

Now, this happens often but not always. the first $d$ you have in mind for which the negative Pell equation is impossible is $d=34.$ The smallest such odd (nonsquare) numbers are $d=205$ and $d=221.$ Note that for a prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ $p$ is always (primitively) the sum of two squares, and the negative Pell equation $u^2 - p v^2 = -1$ is always possible. There is a short proof in Mordell's book *Diophantine Equations*. If you want, I typeset Mordell's proof for another MSE answer, if i cannot find that I can paste the proof here or in another answer from my Latex original file.

So, my advice on this one is to also check negative Pell for all your numbers.

========================

d = 34, 205, 221  NO negative Pell

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
34

0  form   1 10 -9   delta  -1
1  form   -9 8 2   delta  4
2  form   2 8 -9   delta  -1
3  form   -9 10 1   delta  10
4  form   1 10 -9

 disc   136
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
5  54
6  65


 Pell automorph 
35  204
6  35

Pell unit 
35^2 - 34 * 6^2 = 1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
205

0  form   1 28 -9   delta  -3
1  form   -9 26 4   delta  6
2  form   4 22 -21   delta  -1
3  form   -21 20 5   delta  4
4  form   5 20 -21   delta  -1
5  form   -21 22 4   delta  6
6  form   4 26 -9   delta  -3
7  form   -9 28 1   delta  28
8  form   1 28 -9

 disc   820
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
881  24948
2772  78497


 Pell automorph 
39689  568260
2772  39689

Pell unit 
39689^2 - 205 * 2772^2 = 1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
221

0  form   1 28 -25   delta  -1
1  form   -25 22 4   delta  6
2  form   4 26 -13   delta  -2
3  form   -13 26 4   delta  6
4  form   4 22 -25   delta  -1
5  form   -25 28 1   delta  28
6  form   1 28 -25

 disc   884
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-97  -2800
-112  -3233


 Pell automorph 
-1665  -24752
-112  -1665

Pell unit 
-1665^2 - 221 * -112^2 = 1 

=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ date
Wed May 29 12:43:50 PDT 2013
```

=================

Comment: Thank you very much. 
While I have a reservation regarding $d=n^2+1$ (namely that $d=n^2+1$ must automatically be an “all time high” being the starting point after $d=n^2$ and therefore proves little in my pattern of similarity) I find the -1-approach very interesting.  We have now $(a^2+b^2)^2+(c^2+d^2)y^2=-1$ in some cases I would like to look at. My background as a physicist has made me look for a cyclic pattern between squares,   considering whether the equation solutions might be similar to the electron shells, i.e. a similar patter repeating itself between closed shells.

Comment: @MikaelJensen, what are you using to find your Pell solutions? I ask because the Lagrange "neighboring forms" method I use in C++ uses the minimum possible resources, no decimal accuracy is required (the single "oversized" calculation is the integer part, or floor, $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$) and no memory is used.

Comment: I have no computer skills. I use  wolframalpha or http://unafold.math.rpi.edu/cgi-bin/pell.cgi?D=29  (Note that Wolframalpha has x=9801, y=1820)  for d=29, whereas a lower solution is x=70,y=13 from the link above.)

Comment: @MikaelJensen, the difference is that your unafold link gives a solution for $-1,$ as in $70^2 - 29 \cdot 13^2 = -1.$ The simple relationships are $70^2 + 29 \cdot 13^2 = 9801$ and $2 \cdot 70 \cdot 13 = 1820.$

Comment: Thank you. I am really surprised to see this. And I who complained to WolframAlpha. They probably thought I was crazy because they havent answered my email except for the automatic polite respons.